# jQuery Split where numeric number occur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string  like

this-is-my-0-string.
this-is-my-new-1-string-occur.

i want to break string where number occurs

like

this-is-my , 0 , string

and this-is-my-new,1, string-occur

in common words i need to break my string where numbers occur. number is any from 0, 99999 
is it possible to do in javascript or jquery ? How to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: i tried simple split function . it doesnot make sense

Comment: You should split with regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's using split alright.

```
var string1 = "this-is-my-0-string. this-is-my-new-1-string-occur.";

var parts = string1.split(/-(\d)-/);

alert(parts);
```

You can play around [here](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/mEaKh).

Comment: you may use split(/-(\d)-/) too

Comment: interesting, care to explain what the parenthesis does? I tried it without the parenthesis, and it removes the digits from the result.

Comment: @kennypu It's to find the match and remember the match. See from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses

Comment: Definitely `split(/-(\d)-/)`, not `split(/(\d)/)`. The OP's examples show the `-` on either side eaten.

Comment: +1, *I did not know that `split` could use captures*. More: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14